# Parsing a big text file, extract data & store it in a CSV file.. Too Slow

Tags: python, file, parsing, csv

I have a big log file (say 1-3 Gb) which I need to parse, extract data & save it in a CSV file.

Text File Data

```
  *    D:40035FC8 wr-long         00000008 \\core0\Global\u4TimeHiCnt         1.000us
  *    D:40027C5C rd-byte               00 *core0\Global\Ypf_OILL_OilLvlOn   20.342us
  *    D:40010044 rd-word             0FE2 *l\u2SAD_OILLVS_RecoveryCounter    0.160us
  *    D:40010044 wr-word             0FE1 *l\u2SAD_OILLVS_RecoveryCounter    0.040us
  *    D:40035FC8 wr-long         00000008 \\core0\Global\u4TimeHiCnt         1.000us
```

I have to extract the variable name which is after the last \ and then the number of Read & Write along with the datatype & store it in a CSV file.

CSV File Result

```
Variable        Datatype     CORE 0      CORE 1      CORE X 
                          Read   Write   Read    Write   Read    Write 

 OS_inKernel         byte   0     0      111768 111878     0    0

 OS_globalIntLevel   long   0     0      281604 237901     0    0
```

The problem is it takes too much time. Can you pls look in to the attached code & suggest ways to make it faster.

```
import string
import sys
import time

MyFile = open("C:\\Users\\AEC_FULL\\Saravanan\\Workspace\\Trace32Log_Parser\\core1_sram_ReadWrite.txt")#core0_sram_ReadWrite_rawdata

GeneratedFile = open(str(("C:\\Users\\AEC_FULL\\Saravanan\\Workspace\\Trace32Log_Parser\\")+'ParsedOutput.csv'),'w')

try:

    MyVariableList = []
    TimeStartTest       = time.time()        #Starting Time     

    GeneratedFile.write('\nVariable')
    GeneratedFile.write(', Datatype')
    GeneratedFile.write(', CORE 0')
    GeneratedFile.write(',, CORE 1')
    GeneratedFile.write(',, CORE X')

    GeneratedFile.write('\n,, Read ')
    GeneratedFile.write(', Write ')

    GeneratedFile.write(', Read ')
    GeneratedFile.write(', Write ')

    GeneratedFile.write(', Read ')
    GeneratedFile.write(', Write ')                            
    GeneratedFile.write('\n')      



    for CurrentLine in MyFile:

        NoofSpaces = 0

        if CurrentLine.find('\\') != -1:
            MyVariable     = CurrentLine[CurrentLine.rfind('\\')+1:].split(' ')[0]             
        elif CurrentLine.find('*\\') != -1:
            MyVariable     = CurrentLine[CurrentLine.rfind('*\\')+1:].split(' ')[0]             
        elif CurrentLine.find('*') != -1:                
            MyVariable     = CurrentLine[CurrentLine.rfind('*')+1:].split(' ')[0]    

        VariableFound = 0            
        MyVariableList.sort()

        Lowerbound = 0
        Upperbound = len(MyVariableList)-1

        while Lowerbound <= Upperbound and VariableFound == 0:
            middle_pos = (Lowerbound+Upperbound) // 2
            if MyVariableList[middle_pos] < MyVariable:
                Lowerbound = middle_pos + 1
            elif MyVariableList[middle_pos] > MyVariable:
                Upperbound = middle_pos - 1
            else:
                VariableFound = 1        

        if VariableFound == 0:            
            MyVariableList.append(MyVariable) 
            try:
                MyFile1 = open("C:\\Users\\AEC_FULL\\Saravanan\\Workspace\\Trace32Log_Parser\\core1_sram_ReadWrite.txt")#core0_sram_ReadWrite_rawdata

                Core0_ReadCount  = 0
                Core0_WriteCount = 0
                Core1_ReadCount  = 0
                Core1_WriteCount = 0
                CoreX_ReadCount  = 0
                CoreX_WriteCount = 0                    
                for CurrentLine1 in MyFile1:

                    if CurrentLine1.find(MyVariable) != -1:
                        ##   CORE 0  ##
                        if CurrentLine1.find("0\\Global") != -1:
                            DataType        = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[1]
                            DataOperation   = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[0].split(' ')[-1]
                            if DataOperation == 'rd':
                                Core0_ReadCount = Core0_ReadCount + 1
                            elif DataOperation == 'wr':
                                Core0_WriteCount = Core0_WriteCount + 1                                              
                        ##   CORE 1  ##                        
                        elif CurrentLine1.find("1\\Global") != -1:                                
                            DataType        = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[1]
                            DataOperation   = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[0].split(' ')[-1]
                            if DataOperation == 'rd':
                                Core1_ReadCount = Core1_ReadCount + 1
                            elif DataOperation == 'wr':
                                Core1_WriteCount = Core1_WriteCount + 1                            
                        ##   CORE X  ##                        
                        else:
                            DataType        = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[1]
                            DataOperation   = CurrentLine1.split('         ')[0].split('-')[0].split(' ')[-1]
                            if DataOperation == 'rd':
                                CoreX_ReadCount =  CoreX_ReadCount + 1
                            elif DataOperation == 'wr':
                                CoreX_WriteCount = CoreX_WriteCount + 1

                GeneratedFile.write('\n %s' %MyVariable)
                GeneratedFile.write(', %s' %DataType)                            
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %Core0_ReadCount)
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %Core0_WriteCount)             
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %Core1_ReadCount)
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %Core1_WriteCount)  
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %CoreX_ReadCount)
                GeneratedFile.write(', %d' %CoreX_WriteCount)                            
                GeneratedFile.write('\n')                                                    


            finally:
                MyFile1.close()            

except:

    print sys.exc_info()       

finally:

    GeneratedFile.close()  
    MyFile.close()
    TimeStopTest       = time.time()
    print str(int((TimeStopTest - TimeStartTest)/60))
```

Comment: If you have functioning code and want suggestions for speeding it up would it not better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Try changing the logic to remove the `split()` calls as they generate temporary arrays. Instead do another call to find() to find the white space and then use a slice of the exact contents that you want to extract from the file.

Comment: My first impression would be that you're making 9 write calls per line of output. That's INPUT/OUTPUT. The slowest thing you can make a program do. Try turning those into one call. Ultimately though you want to profile your code: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `with` statement, like this:

```
# if this file is line based
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # process line, do something with line
```